# When using cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, how can I use tags to filter both Specs and Features?

Tags: javascript, tags, cucumber, cypress, cypress-grep

I have my Cypress project setup so that I can write and run both Spec and Cucumber tests in one go.

`cypress run --spec "cypress/tests/gsac/specs/*.cy.js,cypress/tests/gsac/*.feature"`

Works great! All test results in one report.

But now I need to filter what I run. Filtering by test name is not flexible enough. Cucumber has excellent tagging features using AND/OR expressions to filter by tags.

```
// Feature files
@smoke
Feature: A critical thing
  @slow
  Scenario: A thing that is slow to test.

@smoke
Feature: A critical thing
```

```bash
# Run syntax
cypress run --spec "cypress/tests/integration/*.cy.js,cypress/tests/integration/*.feature" \
--env tags='@smoke and not @slow'
```

This only filters the Cucumber tests so all Spec tests are run.

**Does anyone know a working solution for Cypress + Cucumber tags + Spec tags?**

I've researched various libraries for filtering Specs, but I can't find ne that is fully compatible with cypress-cucumber-preprocessor.

- [cypress-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-tags) - Not compatible. Throws an exception for any tag on a Feature or Scenario. That's too bad b/c it supports tag expressions similar to Cucumber.
- [cypress-cucumber-tagging](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-tagging) - Not compatible. When installed, all Cucumber tests are skipped. Also supports Cucumber tag expressions, argh.
- [cypress-grep](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/grep) - This is the closest I've gotten but it is not fully compatible. For a given run you can use `tags=''` for Cucumber **OR** `grepTags=''` for Spec but not both. If both env vars are set then all Cucumber tests are skipped. So I this forces me to separate builds/reports for Spec vs Cuke which I really don't want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Both `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` and `@cypress/grep` alter the `specPattern` setting to achieve tag filtering. So potentially there's a conflict depending on how things are configured.

`@cypress/grep` has two alternative configuration approaches - in `cypress/support/e2e` or in `cypress.config.ts`.

Using the config approach works in my project

**cypress.config.ts**

```js
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";
import createBundler from "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor";
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";
import createEsbuildPlugin from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild";

async function setupNodeEvents(
  on: Cypress.PluginEvents,
  config: Cypress.PluginConfigOptions
): Promise<Cypress.PluginConfigOptions> {

  await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);
  on("file:preprocessor", createBundler({ plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)] }));

  if (config.env.tags) {
    config.env.grepTags = config.env.tags        // set grepTags to be same as tags
    config.env.grepFilterSpecs = true
    require('@cypress/grep/src/plugin')(config);
  }
  return config;
}

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.{cy.ts,feature}",   // both extension types
    setupNodeEvents,
    env: {
      "filterSpecsMixedMode": "show",      // for cucumber, allow specs
    }
  },
})
```

The command line is just

```js
"scripts": {
  "cy:run": "cypress run --env tags=@smoke",
```

I have the following features and specs - a.* have `@smoke` tags and b.* do not.

**a.feature**

```js
@smoke
Feature: some feature
  Scenario: first scenario
    Given a step
```

**b.feature**

```js
Feature: some other feature
  Scenario: second scenario
    Given a step
```

**a.cy.ts**

```js
it('passes', { tags: '@smoke' }, () => {
  cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io')
})
```

**b.cy.ts**

```js
it('b passes', () => {
  cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io')
})
```

***Results***

```js
  (Run Finished)


       Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped
  ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ √  a.cy.ts                                00:03        1        1        -        -        - │
  ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
  │ √  a.feature                              188ms        1        1        -        -        - │
  ├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
  │ √  b.feature                              122ms        1        -        -        1        - │
  └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    √  All specs passed!                      00:03        3        2        -        1        -
```

`b.cy.ts` is omitted from the run because of the `config.env.grepFilterSpecs:true` setting. This seems to be required to make things work on the spec (grep) side.

`b.feature` is included in the run but skipped because it does not have the tag.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer!

Unfortunately I have not had success in making this work in our project. Cukes are filtered, Specs are not.

I did notice in the cypress grep docs that using grepFilterSpecs is not compatible with negative filters. So you can't do...

`grepTags=@smoke-slow`

That's not a deal breaker, it just means the tag expressions are limited to inclusion.

Comment: You would need to provide details of how your project differs to this example, obviously this one works.

Comment: Cypress Grep documentation says you **can** run negative filters - [NOT tags](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/develop/npm/grep#not-tags).